# Pull data from others sheets using drop down list

Tags: excel

I have two sheets, in sheet2 I store all the data for each month. In sheet1 I want to do the calculaions for each month using many duffrent formula. In Sheet1 I created a drop down list that takes the months names from Sheet2. What I want to do is when I select for example January, January numbers will show and the calculations will be done for only January. Here is a capture of Sheet 2 and Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet2 show the data (this is an example)]

[image: Sheet1 where I selec a month and calculations will be done for that month (this is an example)]

I found something using VLOOKUP AND INDIRECT but it assign the selectd item from select list as a sheet name.

```
=VLOOKUP(B6,INDIRECT(""&$C$1&"!b2:c11"),2,0)
```

In the list items I have the months from Sheet2..
[image: List items from Sheet2]

Is their a possiable way to do that? because I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think `SUMPRODUCT()` formula will meet your requirement. So, when you selct any month from dropdown list then `SUMPRODUCT()` formula will catch related value from `sheet2` for that month and particulars. Then you can do further calculation with that value like 15% plus, minus blah blah. Here is formula to get value from `sheet2` to `sheet1` for selected month...

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$B$9:$E$9=$C$9)*(Sheet2!$A$10:$A$13=$A10)*(Sheet2!$B$10:$E$13))
```

[image]

`INDEX(), MATCH()` will also work in this case.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$10:$E$13,MATCH($A10,Sheet2!$A$10:$A$13,0),MATCH($C$9,Sheet2!$B$9:$E$9,0))
```